# docker plugin not running parallel builds

Tags: jenkins, docker

I am using docker plugin in jenkins to do our maven builds. We have about 100 builds and we want to run them in parallel using this plugin. Issue is that if all the 100 builds have same label and this label is used in the "template" portion of the plugin, it only runs one build at a time no matter how much instance capacity or container cap we set to. Is there any was that we can run more then one build without assigning different labels to diff jobs and then creating diff templates with those labels?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, somewhat older question, but just fyi: This should really work with current versions. I've running jenkins and docker plugin and it builds even maven jobs in parallel. For detailed analysis, the jenkins log files tells what is happening with the container instantiation.